# Running a Exchange 2013 script through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to setup a script to run with scheduled task each night for Exchange 2013.  I have created a .ps1 that runs the exchange cmdlet and then the script that I want ran follows.  The issues that I am having it that the script is not running after PowerShell access Exchange.

Here is the script:

powershell.exe -NonInteractive -noexit -command ". 'E:\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell"

Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "Room" -BookingWindowInDays (New-timespan -Start (GET-Date) -End 12/1/16).days

If I copy the script and paste it into PowerShell it works but if I right click on the .ps1 file and select "Run in PowerShell" it connects to Exchange but does not run the rest.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having a 'script' call PowerShell - is this a `.bat` file that you've configured?  That would make sense, hence why you right-click, run in PowerShell, and nothing happens (because no parameters were sent - all the `Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell` information is missing).

Comment: It will eventually be used for a scheduled task to run each night.  It connects to exchange.  This part of the script works fine:  powershell.exe -NonInteractive -noexit -command ". 'E:\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell"  The second part of the script does not work when I try to run the .ps1 file.  If I copy both parts and paste them into PowerShell it calls up exchange and then runs the other part and I get the desired out come.

Comment: Are you right-clicking on `RemoteExchange.ps1` file?  If so, that is the root cause of your problem.  Right-click the `.bat` file (you didn't answer this) instead, and see if that works when you run it.  If so, there's your problem.

Comment: My file name is Room.ps1.  I am not running a .bat file.  Is there a way to get the script to wait while Exchange is loading the run the other part.

Comment: Bingo!  ;)  So you're sending parameters from Room.ps1, and when you right-click the RemoteExchange, it doesn't complete all the way, right?

Comment: When I right click Room.ps1 it doesnt complete all the way.

Comment: Can you see why your original question was confusing?  I would click [edit] and clarify the information we've discussed here.  With that information, this could earn you some privileges here, as it will be better formed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the format that I use when I run Exchange tasks from within a Powershell script.

```
# Make a Powershell connection to Exchange
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "Room" -BookingWindowInDays (New-timespan -Start (GET-Date) -End 12/1/16).days
```

I call this from a scheduled task that runs under an account that has rights to do what I am asking it to do.

Within task scheduler:
Under actions in scheduled tasks: `Start a program`.
Program/script: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
Add arguments (optional): `.\ScriptIWantToRun.ps1`
Start in (optional): `C:\Path\To\Script`

The reason that I do it this way is that it works for me and as well I can load other modules besides Exchange.  If you continue to have issues you might want to have your script out-file something to see if it is even starting and maybe get some info on what step it doesn't do anything at.

Just for someone that might have 2010 or 2007 the below might help you with using my above example.

(For **Exchange 2010** under Add arguments (optional): `-version 2 .\ScriptIWantToRun.ps1`)